# Run Groovy JUnit tests in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy

I have a groovy-maven application that is being built in Jenkins. However, my JUnit test suite is not being run. What do I need to put in my pom file to run my JUnits automatically during the build?

The build is correct otherwise.

Comment: Provide more details to what command are you using, how are you executing the job and what is your current pom.xml/

Answer (score 0):

In my maven-surefire-plugin I'd been trying to tell it to use src/test/groovy. But, by removing that and changing my folder names to src/test/java maven could find my tests.

There was probably a configuration somewhere I was missing, but ultimately it was easier to just go with the maven default.

Comment: Literally I just renamed my test package to src/test/java instead of src/test/groovy

Comment: I had to call it groovy instead of java when using GMavenPlus